# react native camera roll .heic files

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ios11, camera-roll

The new .HEIC files on IOS 11 is causing problems because image hosting services to not support it.

The camera roll api is returning.HEIC files. How can we get .JPG/.PNG instead. Or convert .HEIC to .JPG/.PNG

Comment: Maybe you can use a converter for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
ImagePicker.showImagePicker(options, imgResponse => {

this.setState({ imageLoading: true, avatarMediaId: null });

if ((imgResponse.didCancel) || (imgResponse.error)) {
    this.setState({ imageLoading: false });
} else {
    let source = {};
    let fileName = imgResponse.fileName;
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios' && (fileName.endsWith('.heic') || fileName.endsWith('.HEIC'))) {
        fileName = `${fileName.split(".")[0]}.JPG`;
    }
    source = { uri: imgResponse.uri, fileName };
    this.uploadImage(source);
}});
```